# javascript remove attribute when key in

Tags: jquery

if i click "SAME" value is default = 6 but when i click "Wrong" user are allow to enter new value

problem
 value not change when i enter in enable textfield and need to click back "SAME"

```
<button id="same">Wrong</button>
<button id="true">True</button>
<button id="false">False</button>
<input id="test" value=""/> 



$('#same').click(function() {
if ($(this).text() === 'Wrong') {
     $(this).text('Same');
     $('#true').prop('disabled',true);
     $('#false').prop('disabled',true); 
     $('#test').attr('value','6').prop('disabled',true);
}
else {
    $(this).text('Wrong');
     $('#true').prop('disabled',false);
     $('#false').prop('disabled',false);
     $('#test').attr('value','').prop('disabled',false);
}});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/greencat/d3q75/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) at this context. since `.attr()` would change the attribute present with that input element but it would not change the value which is getting displayed. And it renders the changes only for the first time when the page loads.

```
$('#same').click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === 'Wrong') {
         $(this).text('Same');
         $('#true').prop('disabled',true);
         $('#false').prop('disabled',true); 
         $('#test').val('6').prop('disabled',true);
    }
    else {
        $(this).text('Wrong');
         $('#true').prop('disabled',false);
         $('#false').prop('disabled',false);
         $('#test').val('').prop('disabled',false);
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d3q75/2/)

Answer (score 1):

To change the currently displayed value, use:

```
$('#test').val('6');
```

instead of:

```
$('#test').attr('value','6');
```

The initial display value comes from the `value` attribute, but after that, the current value is modified by changing the `.value` property (not the attribute) which is what `.val()` does.

Answer (score 1):

To Assign a value by using jQuery just use val(); method.

In your code just change the

`$('#test').attr('value','6').prop('disabled',true);`

to

```
`$('#test').val('6').prop('disabled',true);
```

And

```
$('#test').attr(value,'').prop('disabled',false);
```

to

```
$('#test').val('').prop('disabled',false);
```